# Characters with accents fail to write on Java Server Pages while creating Rss document

Tags: java, groovy, encoding, utf-8, rss

While creating rss it fails to Italian words 
"Stage Contabilità Franchising" having ascent characters
in the below code it fails to compile

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <rss version="2.0">  <channel>
 <title> ${company?.companyName } </title> <item>   <link>
 https://${tenant?.companyCode?.toLowerCase()}.guru.jobs/hrJobApplication/create?webCode=${company?.webCode
 }&#38;lang=${vacancy?.language?.description}&#38;vacancyId=${vacancy?.id } </link>     <title>         ${vacancy?.position}//Stage Contabilità
 Franchising    </title>        <description> <!--other details-->
 </description> </item> </channel> </rss>
```

Comment: How does it fail? Question marks? What processes that file?

Comment: RSS allows a <language> element.  Does using that help?